# App Engine + Polymer.dart single page web app routing with hashbang

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I'm creating a single page web app using polymer.dart and wants to deploy it on google app engine. I'm stack at routing

I'm using redstone and shelf_static for my server and route_hierarchical for my client.

#### bin/server.dart

```
import 'package:appengine/appengine.dart';

import 'package:redstone/server.dart' as app;
import 'package:shelf_static/shelf_static.dart';

main() {
  var staticHandler = createStaticHandler("web", 
      defaultDocument: "index.html", serveFilesOutsidePath: true);

  app.setShelfHandler(staticHandler);

  app.setupConsoleLog();
  app.setUp();

  runAppEngine(app.handleRequest);
}
```

#### lib/main_app/main_app.dart

```
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

import 'package:route_hierarchical/client.dart';

@CustomTag('main-app')
class MainApp extends PolymerElement {
  final Router router = new Router();

  MainApp.created() : super.created();

  ready() {
    print("Main App: ready()");

    router.root
      ..addRoute(name: 'home', path: '/', enter: showHome, defaultRoute: true)
      ..addRoute(name: 'login', path: '/#!/login', enter: showLogin);

    router.listen();
  }

  void showHome(RouteEvent event) {
    print("Main App: showHome()");
  }

  void showLogin(RouteEvent event) {
    print("Main App: showLogin()");
  }
}
```

#### lib/main_app/main_app.html

#### web/index.html

#### Pages

- Home: localhost:8080/
- Login: localhost:8080/#!/login

If I run the app locally using "pub serve" command, it works. 
However if i run it on appengine using "gcloud preview app run app.yaml" command, the login route isn't working and logs an error. 
http://prntscr.com/77adww

Comment: Did you intend to add source for `web/index.html`?

Comment: thanks for editting, nope, only main_app.dart and server.dart

Comment: Looks weird. Any idea what library it is unable to find at `http:/localhost:8080/#!/login`? Do you have `pub serve` still running on port `8080` while you try to access your app running inside Docker on the same port?

Comment: I have no idea what library it is and theres no pub server running. I only run the ff commands: "boot2docker up", "$(boot2docker shellinit)", "pub build", "gcloud preview app run app.yaml"

Comment: The `index.html` loads fine but when you navigate to `#!/login` you get the error?

Comment: Seems like the browser reloads the page when you click login. This shouldn't happen. Can you publish a minimal example which allows to reproduce the problem on GitHub?

Comment: Yeah sure, give me a minute

Comment: Heres the github repo, https://github.com/xdgimf/polymerdartappengine

Comment: Thanks for the repo, that is very helpful. `gcloud preview app run app.yaml` works fine for me. I click the login link and the login form is shown (`Dart VM version: 1.11.0-edge.45586 (Thu May  7 03:23:52 2015) on "linux_x64"
`).

Comment: Fwiw, it looks like you are running the untransformed output. The `InitializationCrawler` is a development time only thing, and should be replaced with a static list of initializers at compile time.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks man, does visiting the link directly #!/login or using the address bar displays the form?

Comment: I just tried clicking the link, but the address bar was updated.

Comment: Yeah it works, but when I click login then refresh the page, It doesn't work

Comment: Now I understand, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it working! The problem was, I was running the untransformed output just like @Jake MacDonald said. here's how

replace

```
var staticHandler = createStaticHandler("web", defaultDocument: "index.html", serveFilesOutsidePath: true);
```

with

```
var staticHandler = createStaticHandler("build/web", defaultDocument: "index.html", serveFilesOutsidePath: true);
```